# How to see full query in New Relic

Tags: php, sql, database, performance, newrelic

When I go to APM > Applications > PHP Application > Databases it shows the list of queries and their performance. But the queries are shown like `<table name> select`. How can I see the full query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/nodejs-agent-configuration#tx_tracer_config you have to set the `record_sql` configuration to either `'raw'` or `'obfuscated'`. By default it is `'off'` so you won't see the SQL.

Keep in mind that this is in the `transaction_tracer` sections. So for Node.js for instance (I know you're using PHP), you would do:

```
{
  transaction_tracer: {
    record_sql: 'raw',
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a paid account with New Relic, you will have access to slow SQL queries and Transaction Traces; these will show up in the UI if the apdex_f is reached for transactions.

More info here:
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/monitoring/view-slow-query-details

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He says the statistics are showing up, but the full text of the query is not, just "Tablename select".